# How can I get the Client Certificate in Netty Handler to identify user?

Tags: ssl, certificate, netty

I am successfully running Netty with 2-way SSL (see [Set up Netty with 2-way SSL Handsake (client and server certificate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573894/set-up-netty-with-2-way-ssl-handsake-client-and-server-certificate)).

However, in some of my handlers, I need to know about the user who is using the application.  I find that I can't figure out how to get information like the user certificate DN in my handlers.

I would think it would be available in the ChannelHandlerContext somewhere but it is not.  Any suggestions?

I know the SSLEngine has access to it somewhere, but I don't see anything about obtaining access in the SSLEngine public API.  I know it has access in the handshake operation.... but how do I get it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SSLEngine.getSession().getPeerCertificateChain()`. The zeroth entry is the peer's own certificate.

Comment: Play! Framework uses netty in its background and I want the SSL client certificate, how could I get the current SSLEngine??

Answer (score 11):

The SSLEngine can be fetched through the Pipline/ChannelHandlerContext

```
ChannelHandlerContext ctx = ...
SslHandler sslhandler = (SslHandler) ctx.channel().pipeline().get("ssl");
sslhandler.engine().getSession().getPeerCertificateChain()[0].getSubjectDN());
```

This allows you to get the certificates in the Handler Objects. Pay attention, that the SSL-Handshake needs to be finished when you do this. Otherwise you will get a

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

exception. To avoid this, you can listen for a userEvent (in our case HandshakeCompletionEvent) in the handler, which could look the following:

```
@Override
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) {
    logger.info("userEventTriggered: {0}, Class: {1}", evt.toString(), evt.getClass());

    if (evt instanceof HandshakeCompletionEvent) {
        fetchCertificate(ctx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the following codes to get the client certificate and certificate's issuer. I hope it helps.

```
 SslHandler sslHandler = (SslHandler) ctx.channel().pipeline().get("ssl");

 X509Certificate issuer = convert(sslHandler.engine().getSession().getPeerCertificateChain()[sslHandler.engine().getSession().getPeerCertificateChain().length -1]);

 System.out.println("issuer: " + issuer);


  public static java.security.cert.X509Certificate convert(javax.security.cert.X509Certificate cert) {
    try {
        byte[] encoded = cert.getEncoded();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(encoded);
        java.security.cert.CertificateFactory cf
                = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        return (java.security.cert.X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(bis);
    } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException e) {
    } catch (javax.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException e) {
    } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why? You already have the certificate. Why encode it and decode it all over again? The `convert()` method is pointless here.